# DatePickerDialog range for 7 days

Tags: android

I am using final DatePickerDialog as

```
 DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =
                        new DatePickerDialog(SendLogActivity.this, startDateListener, calendarStart
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarStart.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                calendarStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                datePickerDialog.show();
```

where startDateListener  is

```
private final OnDateSetListener startDateListener = new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(final DatePicker view, final int year, final int monthOfYear,
                final int dayOfMonth) {

            trackingUtil.log("Date set");
            calendarStart.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            calendarStart.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendarStart.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        }
    };
```

i wants to set a range in the DatePicker for just 7 days how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get the DatePicker from the dialog with `DatePickerDialog.getDatePicker()` and then you can use `DatePicker.setMaxDate()` and `DatePicker.setMinDate()` to set your range

Answer (score 2):

You can get the underlying `DatePicker` from a `DatePickerDialog` (by simply calling `getDatePicker()`) and set its bounds using:

```
setMinDate(long minDate)
setMaxDate(long maxDate)
```

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)